# can we transfer custom token from one contract function to another contract?

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, contract-invocation, transfer

can we transfer custom token from one contract function to another contract ? I want to transfer some custom tokens to another contract whilst using a contract function. Is this possible ?

e.g:

```
contract A {
  someFunction() {
   transfer(msg.sender,0x46197d03E60de6cA6fB5e8886Aa350fF9591254f,100);
  }
}

contract B { //already deployed in another .sol file
  //contract B address is 0x46197d03E60de6cA6fB5e8886Aa350fF9591254f
}
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Please, can you explain better your issue?

Comment: @Kerry99 check now